# Sum elements in python list only if elements in a separate boolean list are True

Tags: python, boolean, comparison, list-comprehension

I have two python lists,

```
A = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
B = [ True, False, False, True, True ]
```

lists A and B are the same length.

I want to sum only the elements in A that correspond to True elements in B.
I know I can do that with something like:

```
sum([A[x] for x in xrange(len(A)) if B[x]])
```

but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution that didn't involve looping over elements in each list?

Comment: If `A` and `B` where `numpy.array`s. All you would have to do: `A[B].sum()`.

Answer (score 6):

Using [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> sum(compress(A, B))
10
```

The implementation of `itertools.compress` is described on the linked page. It's short and simple, so you don't *have* to import `itertools` <sup>1</sup>:

```
>>> sum(a for a, b in zip(A, B) if b)
10
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> OTOH, `itertools.compress` is implemented in C, and therefore should be faster</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Generator expression + `sum`:

```
>>> A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> B = [True, False, False, True, True]
>>> sum(a for a,b in zip(A, B) if b)
10
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
A = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
B = [ True, False, False, True, True ]

sum_ = sum([numa for (numa, numb) in zip(A, B) if numb])
print(sum_)
```

**Out**

```
10
```

**How it works:**

If we expand the list comprehension a little more we can see what is happening a little more clearly.

```
nums_to_sum = []
for numa, numb in zip(A, B):
     if numb:
         nums_to_sum.append(numa)
sum_ = sum(nums_to_sum)
```