# Summing values in a list where the other list index is a 1?

Tags: python, list, lambda

I have two lists:

```
list_1 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
list_2 = [34, 54, 23, 54, 656 34, 100]
```

I want to sum only the values in `list_2` where the index in `list_2` matches the value of 1 for the same index in `list_1`.

Example here would be `54 + 100 = 154`

How can I do this in Python in a Pythonic way?

Comment: [Sum elements in python list only if elements in a separate boolean list are True](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36504738/2301450)

Answer (score 7):

Just use [`compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) from `itertools` and feed it to `sum`; it's built for this purpose:

```
from itertools import compress 
r = sum(compress(list_2, list_1))
```

Answer (score 6):

Zip the lists, then sum only values where the first element is `1`:

```
s = sum(b for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2) if a)
```

Another zip approach would be an element-wise multiplication between the lists (thus eliminating elements whose parallel is `0`):

```
s = sum(a * b for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably less pythonic, but also works for lists of similar size:

```
>>> l1 = [0,1,0,0,1]
>>> l2 = [10,23,45,1,23]
>>> map(lambda x,y: x*y , l1,l2)
[0, 23, 0, 0, 23]
>>> sum(map(lambda x,y: x*y , l1,l2))
46
>>>
```